# Set variable text column width in printf

Tags: c, size, printf

In order to determine the size of the column in C language we use `%<number>d`.
For instance, I can type `%3d` and it will give me a column of width=3.
My problem is that my number after the `%` is a variable that I receive, so I need something like `%xd` (where `x` is the integer variable I received sometime before in my program).
But it's not working.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: In general, instead of "not working" you should copy-paste the exact error message you received.

Comment: @luserdroog There is no error message when `printf` fails. It just silently gives incorrecy output.

Comment: Is this related to the eight years old question? And what output do you get and what are you expecting? What does the call look like?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
printf("%*d", width, value);
```

From Lee's comment:
You can also use a * for the precision:

```
printf("%*.*f", width, precision, value);
```

Note that both `width` and `precision` must have type `int` as expected by `printf` for the `*` arguments, type `size_t` is inappropriate as it may have a different size and representation on the target platform.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB: no this does not work for `scanf`: the `*` means *suppress assignment* and no pointer argument is provided for this conversion specification. There is no way to specify the number as an argument, but you can compose a format string with `snprintf` as a work-around. `scanf_s` from optional and controversial Annex K attempted to address related issues, but the specification is inadequate for simple use.

Answer (score 8):

Just for completeness, wanted to mention that with POSIX-compliant versions of [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) you can also put the actual field width (or precision) value somewhere else in the parameter list and refer to it using the 1-based parameter number followed by a dollar sign:

> A field width or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk ‘∗’ or an asterisk followed by one or more decimal digits and a ‘$’ instead of a digit string. In this case, an int argument supplies the field width or precision. A negative field width is treated as a left adjustment flag followed by a positive field width; a negative precision is treated as though it were missing. If a single format directive mixes positional (nn$) and non-positional arguments, the results are undefined.

E.g., `printf ( "%1$*d", width, value );`

Comment: Your example doesn't fit the language. It should be `"%*1$d"`

Comment: Furthermore, you should specify both argument by means of `n$`, like so: `printf("%2$*1$d", width, value);`.