# Printing int values with a user determined padding?

Tags: c, formatting, printf, padding, precision

I'm pretty sure there's no way to do this, but I was wondering, so here goes...

Say I get several int values from the user, and I know for a fact that the 1st 
value is the largest.
Any way I can use the length of the first int value as the padding when printing 
the rest of the numbers?

Browsing the forum I found that you can determine the length of an int (n) like 
this:

```
l = (int) log10(n) + 1;
```

Using padding of 5 a print would look like:

```
printf("%5d", n);
```

So what I want to know is whether or not there's a way to use l instead of 5...

Thank you!

Comment: Actually there is
: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105890/set-variable-text-column-width-in-printf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do it like so:

```
int n = <some value>;
int i = (int) log10(n) + 1;
printf("%*d", i, n);
```

The `*` serves as a placeholder for the *width* being passed as an argument to `printf()`.

Comment: So there IS a way :D Thank you ^^

Comment: @alk What does the `log10(n)` line does?

Comment: @Kraken: It calculates the number of decimal places used by `n`. Also please see the OP for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also `snprintf()` to get the number of characters printed for a value thus:

```
char buff[100];
int width = snprintf (buff, sizeof(buff), "%d", number1);
```

But, however you get the desired width, you can just use the `*` format modifier:

```
printf( "%*d %*d\n", width, number1, width, number2);
```

That modifier uses the next argument to specify a dynamic width rather than one fixed in the format string.