# Java printf error when using asterisks

Tags: java, syntax, printf

Here's the printf statement that's giving me the error:

```
System.out.printf("%-*s%*s", dateTimeWidth, dateTime, locationWidth, location);
```

I want dateTime to be printed left-aligned with width dateTimeWidth and location to be printed right-aligned with width locationWidth. Both locationWidth and dateTimeWidth are passed in as ints.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '-'
    at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2503)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2485)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2414)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:920)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:821)
    at TicketMaker.drawTicket(TicketMaker.java:43)
    at TicketMaker.main(TicketMaker.java:12)
```

I believe something is wrong with my syntax, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Info on printf with asterisks 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105890/set-variable-text-column-width-in-printf)

Comment: What do you think `*` in `%-*s` represents? Also could you share some link where we could read about it?

Comment: I believe you want numbers instead of *'s. http://web.cerritos.edu/jwilson/SitePages/java_language_resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf

Comment: In researching, I may have answered my own question. I believe the * only works in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare an extra variable before using printf:

```
String format = "%-" + dateTimeWidth + "s%" + locationWidth + "s";
System.out.printf(format, dateTime, location);
```