# Is there a way to put a variable inside a string formatting like %04d in C? So I can make it vary depending on the variable results?

Tags: c

```
printf("%04d\n", vet[i]);
```

Is it possible to make something like "%0(x)d" so that the formatting can vary?

Comment: No. But you can construct the format string programmatically before (with `sprintf` for example).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7105890/1216776

Comment: You can also have `printf("%0*d\n", width, vet[i]);` to have more control over the formatting.

Comment: In fact I take my first comment partially back. For the width specification (but not the general formatting) you can use th asterisk notation as in http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p5 (and the answer)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The precision can also be an asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
printf( "%0*d\n", width, vet[i] );
```

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  for ( int i = 1; i < 5; i++ )
  {
    printf( "%0*d\n", i, i );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
02
003
0004
```