# Aligning printf statements in C

Tags: c, string, alignment

I have some values I would like to align to the left. However, two numbers, 2400 and 2500 have extra offsets and I'm assuming its because of the longer key.name that's causing it. What can I do to align the values properly? Is there another alignment method I'm missing on?

My code

```
void print_key(Key key) {
    char c = ' ';
    printf("%-5d%-15s%-40c",key.num, key.name,c);
}

// Input: ’node’: a node
// Effect: node.key is printed and then the node.data is printed
void print_node(Node node) {
    print_key(node.key);
    printf("%d\n", node.data);
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xljLU.png)

Comment: Make the column that currently doesn't fit wider. [Set variable text column width in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105890/set-variable-text-column-width-in-printf) may help. Iterate through all of your data, find the longest item in each column, and dynamically size them appropriately.

Comment: The TL;DR: Change `15s` into (e.g.) `25s` as `Beechmount Crescent` is more than 15 chars long.

Comment: @Retired Ninja Ahh thank you!

Comment: @Craig Estey thank you! both variable text column width and just setting more space works.

Comment: What is the point of the third (invisible) column of 40 characters? Why not simply get rid of it by merging it with the second column, by doing `printf("%-5d%-55s",key.num, key.name);` instead? That way, the second column will be large enough for printing all the names.